# Test Flight issues with Consumable Purchases - RevenueCat

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, revenuecat

I am testing a tvOS (15.2) app that has a subscription and two consumable product IAP. The consumable product IAP works properly when running the tvOS app via Xcode. However, when running the same app via Test Flight, the consumable IAP does not allow the purchase of a second exact consumable and instead provides this message: “The In-app purchase has already been bought. It will be restored for free”. Again this is a consumable purchase so there should be no restoration and the user should be able to purchase it as often as they want. This again does NOT happen when running via Xcode. The consumable IAP is set as consumable on App Store Connect and is not associated with any entitlement on RevenueCat. I am obviously concerned that if it’s happening on TF that it will happen in production as well. Why is this occurring?

I did post on their forums as well, but seeing if anyone has run across that issue here.

The purchase is using their standard:

```
Purchases.shared.purchasePackage(productOffering.package) { (transaction, purchaserInfo, error, userCancelled) in
```

Purchases is configured in the initialization of the app as:

```
Purchases.configure(withAPIKey: "mykey")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the solution to this problem is to use an actual Apple account and not a sandbox user account. When in TF the actual Apple account worked (without actually charging) and allowed multiple purchases of the same consumable IAP as it should. Go figure.